# Best way of implementing this Table in android

Tags: android

I have to implement following table in my application.

[UI design of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJEnW.jpg)

these table data coming from an REST API. I try to implemented this using table header and List view where Linear Layout represent table header and List View. I gave both Linear Layout columns and List item columns same weight hoping that it will display as a table. Since Table data content is usually occupies long space
table header column and List Item column takes different size in the screen. So it doesn't render correctly as a table in UI.

This is app which needs to be perform smoothly. So I can't use Table Layout since I can't use static view holder pattern or Adapter.And most importantly I have to achieve this UI design as it is.

Please suggest me a proper way of addressing this Issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could user RecyclerView with the following custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COLUMN 01"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COLUMN 02"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COLUMN 03"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COLUMN 04"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of stopping scrolling Table header with other. In this way ? I have to provide data array with first value representing table header. am I right ?

Comment: You could create a header with the same layout of the item and put the RecyclerView below it

Comment: Well that's what i did at the first place. since we are using weight for dividing columns width which is decided base on it's content. Table header not gonna have long string value. so it's not gonna have table design.

Comment: width wont be decided based on string value, in the example you are using layout_weight, so it will split the column in 4 equal values